# Imagefield: can't upload image

Tags: django

**Django 1.10**

Could you help me upload image. Request is done via ajax. The view inherits from some mixins. They are just auxiliary to add action or enctype. Well, to present the form as it is rendered. I haven't shown the mixins here.

The result is that the form can't pass validation. Error message for image field: This field is required.

And "No file chosen" appears near the "Choose file" button.

All symptoms as if testify for absence of 'enctype="multipart/form-data"'. Look: in the network tab I can't see that the file was transmitted to the server. And if I try to serialize the form, there is no file mentioned.

This seems not the problem of Django at all: I somehow can't correctly pass the form from the client to the server. The problem seems has something with html.

Well, could you give me a kick here?

**ajax_form.html**

```
<form id="object_form" action="{{ action }}" {% autoescape off %}{{ enctype }}{% endautoescape %} method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
        <table>
            {{ form.as_table }}
        </table>

        <a id="submit" href="javascript:void(0)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-save" aria-hidden="true">Save</span></a>


        <a id="cancel" href="javascript:void(0)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign" aria-hidden="true">Cancel</span></a>

</form>
```

**views.py**

```
class PictureCreate(AddEnctypeMixin, ActionCreateMixin, GetForeignKeyFromUrlMixin, CreateView):
    model = Picture
    form_class = PictureForm
    foreign_key_from_url = "sheet"
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^picture/', include('picture.urls', namespace='picture')),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**settings.py**

```
DEBUG = True
```

**models.py**

```
class Picture(models.Model):
    sheet = models.ForeignKey(Sheet, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=False, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name="Title")
    pic = models.ImageField(verbose_name="Picture", upload_to=upload__path)
```

**Inspect element**

```
<form id="object_form" action="/sheet/3/picture_create/" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="Hs7aKX1nRs2pis357xQ8OFJgCyp2tyjF2MK62l2YxrtSBCnxKKg5RzUb7iWSNaNM">
        <table>
            <tbody><tr><th><label for="id_title">Title:</label></th><td><input id="id_title" maxlength="100" name="title" type="text"></td></tr>
<tr><th><label for="id_pic">Picture:</label></th><td><input id="id_pic" name="pic" type="file" required=""><input id="id_sheet" name="sheet" type="hidden" value="3"></td></tr>
        </tbody></table>

        <a id="submit" href="javascript:void(0)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-save" aria-hidden="true">Save</span></a>


        <a id="cancel" href="javascript:void(0)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign" aria-hidden="true">Cancel</span></a>

</form>
```

**In console before sending via ajax:**

```
$("#object_form").serialize()
"csrfmiddlewaretoken=Hs7aKX1nRs2pis357xQ8OFJgCyp2tyjF2MK62l2YxrtSBCnxKKg5RzUb7iWSNaNM&title=&sheet=3"
```

**Network tab**

```
General

Request URL:http://localhost:8000/sheet/3/picture_create/
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK
Remote Address:127.0.0.1:8000

Response Headers

Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
Date:Sat, 17 Sep 2016 16:17:16 GMT
Server:WSGIServer/0.2 CPython/3.5.2
Set-Cookie:csrftoken=sK40eJ5eIIcddMzOGOoiG8G41H9WminPN4HWw76PoHDGwWTgj1OfJ2RZwrGMGURW; expires=Sat, 16-Sep-2017 16:17:16 GMT; Max-Age=31449600; Path=/
Vary:Cookie
X-Frame-Options:SAMEORIGIN

Request Headers

Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:108
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Cookie:sessionid=gxqv6cg1y8ozve2g6emciiujs9kc1e3c; csrftoken=sK40eJ5eIIcddMzOGOoiG8G41H9WminPN4HWw76PoHDGwWTgj1OfJ2RZwrGMGURW
Host:localhost:8000
Origin:http://localhost:8000
Pragma:no-cache
Referer:http://localhost:8000/sheet/3/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest


Form Data

view URL encoded
csrfmiddlewaretoken:Hs7aKX1nRs2pis357xQ8OFJgCyp2tyjF2MK62l2YxrtSBCnxKKg5RzUb7iWSNaNM
title:adasfasdf
sheet:3
```

**EcmaScript 6**

```
_send_post_request(){
    let object_form = $("#object_form");
    this._button_manager.prevent_default(object_form);

    $.ajax({
        method: "post",
        data: object_form.serialize(),
        url: this._url,
        success: this._show_result.bind(this),
        error: general_fail
    });
}
```

Comment: So what's the js code for the ajax call?

Comment: dan-klasson, I have added it to the end. But, please, remember that ajax can't pass the file to the server as $("#object_form").serialize() doesn't show any file. So, the problem must be on the client side.

Comment: Maybe serialize doesn't work for file fields? Why don't you use `FormData`?

Comment: I'll try. You may be right.